# read.xls not behaving as expected

Tags: r, excel, gdata

I have a excel file (in xls format) like this

```
a             b
10/06/2012  10/06/12 19:00
11/06/2012  11/06/12 05:30
11/06/2012  11/06/12 09:30
11/06/2012  11/06/12 10:00 
11/06/2012  11/06/12 11:00
11/06/2012  11/06/12 11:30
```

I am using read.xls function of gdata library to read this xls file into R.

```
data <- read.xls("data.xlsx")
```

But when open this file in R. I get this

```
a                b
41070          41070.79
41071          41071.23
41071          41071.40
41071          41071.42
41071          41071.46
41071          41071.48
```

I do not know what is happening here. When I use read.csv to read the converted csv file, the file is being read correctly. Can somebody please tell me what is the problem? I am working on Linux machine.

Comment: Have you considered converting with [`as.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) using the correct origin?

Answer (score 1):

Try to format the date in the R readable format 2014-11-25. Then read.xls would work properly. If you need it in the same format try using XLConnect.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates as numbers: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/about-dates-and-date-systems-HP005200674.aspx.

What you got from Excel is precisely those numbers (no. of days which elapsed from January 1, 1900 till your dates.

A way to get your strings unchanged to R would be to convert them in Excel to pure text strings first.